# JavaFX 2 Animation: scale Node depending PathTransition duration

Tags: javafx-2

I want to change the size of a Node on a PathTransition dedending the position (duration) the Node has on the Path.
See: [JavaFX 2 circle path for animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171856/javafx-2-circle-path-for-animation) as an example for the animation.

The Node's size should grow till it reaches the "middle" of the Path and then shrink. I'm wondering there's no EventHandler but onFinished for an Animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated Uluk's sample in this answer to add a ParallelTransition which scales the node as it travels along the path.  For the first half of the path, the node grows in size.  Once the node is halfway along the path, it shrinks in size until it reaches it's original size at the start of the circle.

The animation does have a kind of strange forward motion blur effect when run at high speed (you need to run it to see this) that I can't really explain.

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ArcToScalingDemo extends Application {

  private PathTransition pathTransitionEllipse;
  private ParallelTransition scalingCirclePathTransition;

  private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
    Group root = new Group();
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 460));

    // Ellipse path example
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 40, 40);
    rect.setArcHeight(10);
    rect.setArcWidth(10);
    rect.setFill(Color.ORANGE);
    root.getChildren().add(rect);

    Path path = createEllipsePath(200, 200, 50, 100, 45);
    root.getChildren().add(path);

    pathTransitionEllipse = PathTransitionBuilder.create()
        .duration(Duration.seconds(4))
        .path(path)
        .node(rect)
        .orientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT)
        .cycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE)
        .autoReverse(false)
        .build();

    // Circle path example
    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
    rect2.setArcHeight(10);
    rect2.setArcWidth(10);
    rect2.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    root.getChildren().add(rect2);

    Path path2 = createEllipsePath(400, 200, 150, 150, 0);
    root.getChildren().add(path2);

    PathTransition pathTransitionCircle = PathTransitionBuilder.create()
        .duration(Duration.seconds(2))
        .path(path2)
        .node(rect2)
        .orientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT)
        .cycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE)
        .autoReverse(false)
        .build();

    ScaleTransition scaleTransition = ScaleTransitionBuilder.create()
        .duration(pathTransitionCircle.getDuration().divide(2))
        .fromX(1)
        .fromY(1)
        .toX(3)
        .toY(3)
        .cycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE)
        .autoReverse(true)
        .build();

    scalingCirclePathTransition = ParallelTransitionBuilder.create()
        .children(pathTransitionCircle, scaleTransition)
        .node(rect2)
        .build();
  }

  private Path createEllipsePath(double centerX, double centerY, double radiusX, double radiusY, double rotate) {
    ArcTo arcTo = new ArcTo();
    arcTo.setX(centerX - radiusX + 1); // to simulate a full 360 degree celcius circle.
    arcTo.setY(centerY - radiusY);
    arcTo.setSweepFlag(false);
    arcTo.setLargeArcFlag(true);
    arcTo.setRadiusX(radiusX);
    arcTo.setRadiusY(radiusY);
    arcTo.setXAxisRotation(rotate);

    Path path = PathBuilder.create()
        .elements(
            new MoveTo(centerX - radiusX, centerY - radiusY),
            arcTo,
            new ClosePath()) // close 1 px gap.
        .build();
    path.setStroke(Color.DODGERBLUE);
    path.getStrokeDashArray().setAll(5d, 5d);
    return path;
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    init(primaryStage);
    primaryStage.show();
    pathTransitionEllipse.play();
    scalingCirclePathTransition.play();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

The position the Node has on the Path is not necessarily the same as the relative duration of the time elapsed in the animation because the Node may not be traveling at a constant velocity.  Additionally, in this sample, the relative scale of the node might not match exactly either of those values.  You can define a custom [Interpolator](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Interpolator.html#curve%28double%29) for the ScaleTransition which let's you map the scale to a value dependent on the current path position or animation duration, but it's not really necessary as visually the interpolation looks fine without it to me.

Here's another sample with a custom interpolator which will scale the node in proportion to it's position along the path, such that the node is at maximum scale halfway along the path.  It relies on an interpolation function in the original path transition which is symmetrical.  The sample has not been thoroughly tested for perfect correctness.  Unless absolutely necessary, I would recommend the prior example without a custom interpolator over this one.

```
public class ArcToInterpolation Demo extends Application {

  class HalfInterpolator extends Interpolator {
    final Interpolator source;

    HalfInterpolator(Interpolator source) {
      this.source = source;
    }

    @Override protected double curve(double t) {
      return t <= 0.5
          ? source.interpolate(0.0, 1.0, t) * 2
          : source.interpolate(0.0, 1.0, 1 - t) * 2;
    }
  }

  private ParallelTransition scalingCirclePathTransition;

  private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
    Group root = new Group();
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 460));

    // Circle path example
    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
    rect2.setArcHeight(10);
    rect2.setArcWidth(10);
    rect2.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    root.getChildren().add(rect2);

    Path path2 = createEllipsePath(400, 200, 150, 150, 0);
    root.getChildren().add(path2);

    PathTransition pathTransitionCircle = PathTransitionBuilder.create()
        .duration(Duration.seconds(10))
        .interpolator(Interpolator.EASE_BOTH)
        .path(path2)
        .node(rect2)
        .orientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT)
        .cycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE)
        .autoReverse(false)
        .build();

    ScaleTransition scaleTransition = ScaleTransitionBuilder.create()
        .duration(pathTransitionCircle.getDuration())
        .interpolator(new HalfInterpolator(pathTransitionCircle.getInterpolator()))
        .fromX(1)
        .fromY(1)
        .toX(4)
        .toY(4)
        .cycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE)
        .autoReverse(false)
        .build();

    scalingCirclePathTransition = ParallelTransitionBuilder.create()
        .children(pathTransitionCircle, scaleTransition)
        .node(rect2)
        .build();
  }

  private Path createEllipsePath(double centerX, double centerY, double radiusX, double radiusY, double rotate) {
    ... as in previous sample
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    init(primaryStage);
    primaryStage.show();
    scalingCirclePathTransition.play();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering all my JavaFX questions. If you could provide the interpolator code, maybe I need it later. So far it looks very good. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should use

public final ReadOnlyObjectProperty currentTimeProperty

of PathTransition class. You can add listener on this property's value changing and when a new value appears, call double d = newDuration.toMillis(), and determine, which part of path is gone, dividing d on the full time of animation.

Comment: But I can't add a listener to the PathTransition. So I have to implement a properties changed listener by myself, no easier way?

Comment: I think, the easiest way will look like this:

        pathTransition.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Duration>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> ov, Duration t, Duration t1) {
                double coef = Math.abs(Math.sin(t1.toSeconds())) + 1;
                targetNode.getTransforms().clear();
                targetNode.getTransforms().add(new Scale(coef, coef));
            }
        });

Comment: Thanks for this solution (double-upvote). I think the ParallelTransition is more the FX-way although your answer matches my question perfectly.