# adding path transition to Group in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I'm writing some javaFX code and I have added some Paths to a Group, this Group has been added to another Group which has been added to the root and is displaying on the screen. Now at a certain point I want to use a PathTransition to animate this lowest level group to a new location. I'm having trouble working out the correct coordinates for the transition. I have read that the PathTransition will animate the node from its center and not the upper left hand corner so I have tried adding 
 Group.getLayoutX()/2 to the starting x and Group.getLayoutY()/2 to the starting y coord but it still seems to make the group jump to a new starting location before the animation begins. 
The final destination seems a bit off as well. 
 Is there a better way to animate a Group that contains several Paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the `layoutX` and `layoutY` of the nodes following paths based upon half the layout bounds of the nodes being animated.

```
rect.setLayoutX(rect.getLayoutX() + rect.getLayoutBounds().getWidth()  / 2);
rect.setLayoutY(rect.getLayoutY() + rect.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() / 2);
```

---

Try the modification of Uluk's circle path transition code from [JavaFX 2 circle path for animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171856/javafx-2-circle-path-for-animation).

The code will have the upper left corner of the nodes original layout follow the path.

[image: nodepathsample]

```
import javafx.animation.PathTransition.OrientationType;
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ArcToDemo extends Application {

    private PathTransition pathTransitionEllipse;
    private PathTransition pathTransitionCircle;

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 460));

        // Ellipse path example
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 40, 40);
        rect.setArcHeight(10);
        rect.setArcWidth(10);
        rect.setFill(Color.ORANGE);
        root.getChildren().add(rect);

        Path path = createEllipsePath(200, 200, 50, 100, 45);
        root.getChildren().add(path);

        pathTransitionEllipse = PathTransitionBuilder.create()
                .duration(Duration.seconds(4))
                .path(path)
                .node(rect)
                .orientation(OrientationType.NONE)
                .cycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE)
                .autoReverse(false)
                .build();

        rect.setLayoutX(rect.getLayoutX() + rect.getLayoutBounds().getWidth()  / 2);
        rect.setLayoutY(rect.getLayoutY() + rect.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() / 2);

        // Circle path example
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
        rect2.setArcHeight(10);
        rect2.setArcWidth(10);
        rect2.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        root.getChildren().add(rect2);

        Path path2 = createEllipsePath(400, 200, 150, 150, 0);
        root.getChildren().add(path2);

        pathTransitionCircle = PathTransitionBuilder.create()
                .duration(Duration.seconds(2))
                .path(path2)
                .node(rect2)
                .orientation(OrientationType.NONE)
                .cycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE)
                .autoReverse(false)
                .build();

        rect2.setLayoutX(rect2.getLayoutX() + rect2.getLayoutBounds().getWidth()  / 2);
        rect2.setLayoutY(rect2.getLayoutY() + rect2.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() / 2);
    }

    private Path createEllipsePath(double centerX, double centerY, double radiusX, double radiusY, double rotate) {
        ArcTo arcTo = new ArcTo();
        arcTo.setX(centerX - radiusX + 1); // to simulate a full 360 degree celcius circle.
        arcTo.setY(centerY - radiusY);
        arcTo.setSweepFlag(false);
        arcTo.setLargeArcFlag(true);
        arcTo.setRadiusX(radiusX);
        arcTo.setRadiusY(radiusY);
        arcTo.setXAxisRotation(rotate);

        Path path = PathBuilder.create()
                .elements(
                new MoveTo(centerX - radiusX, centerY - radiusY),
                arcTo,
                new ClosePath()) // close 1 px gap.
                .build();
        path.setStroke(Color.DODGERBLUE);
        path.getStrokeDashArray().setAll(5d, 5d);
        return path;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
        pathTransitionEllipse.play();
        pathTransitionCircle.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

*Implementation Notes*

1. The code assumes that the original layout position of the nodes being animated is 0,0 (if it is not then you will need to adjust accordingly).
2. For non-square nodes, there is a slight gap between the node and the path (because the calculations are based on the layout bounds rectangle and not the visible shape of the node).
3. Also the path transition is using an orientation of `NONE` rather than `ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT` (otherwise the layout calculations give a strange effect as the node starts to rotate and it seems as though the node is traveling divergent to the path).

Instead of the above approach, you could define a custom subclass of [Transition](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Transition.html) which modifies the `TranslateX` and `TranslateY` properties of the node so that the corner of the node follows the path rather than the center and no modifications to the node's layout are required, however that would be significantly more work.

Comment: Thank you so much. I haven't taken the time to read this entire response but just adding in half the layoutBounds to the x and y before animating the Group made my animation look perfect.