# Find an angle representing the direction of travel from origin coordinates

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I'm working on an animation where a number of triangular objects move across the screen. In order to ensure each faces the direction in which it is travelling, I need to rotate the image by the appropriate angle.

My problem is that the angle my code returns does not accurately do this. The values returned do not change by more than a few degrees.

```
/**
 * Accepts two grid positions are arguments. The current position
 * of the object and the next grid position. Returns an angle representing 
 * the direction of travel from the current position towards the next position. By converting the Cartesian coordinates into polar coordinates. 
 *  
 */
public void setAngle(Vector2d currentPos, Vector2d nextPos ) {
    Double delta_x = current.xPos - next.xPos;
    Double delta_y = current.yPos - next.yPos;
    Double theta = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
    this.angle = theta;
}   


Example:

|| current: 1031.1438073417544 , 268.3133503758045 || next: 1033.101761841174 , 269.0819944286846 || Angle: 0.0

|| current: 1033.1901579769194 , 242.19363555578593 || next: 1035.1281222295695 , 243.08778242413436 || Angle: 0.0

|| current: 1022.1577455080815 , 255.24422527831163 || next: 1024.0301966330894 , 256.19078788718997 || Angle: 0.0
```

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer without seeing some code. Note that the Math trig functions work in radians, though, while JavaFX rotations are in degrees.

Comment: You do realize, that the current pos and next pos values in your output are identical?

Comment: Also updated. Grid positions are not changing by more than a few decimal places each time. The previous snapshot happened to be at a time when they were the same.

Comment: You haven't actually added the code that generates the output you show, which certainly doesn't come from applying the computation you show to the values in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// calc the deltas as next minus current
double delta_x = next.xPos - current.xPos;
double delta_y = next.yPos - current.yPos;

// Calc the angle IN RADIANS using the atan2
double theta = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);

// this.angle is now in degrees
// or leave off *180/Math.PI if you want radians
this.angle = theta*180/Math.PI;
```

Comment: When doing computations like this, you should use "double" and not "Double". If you don't do that you will suffer from a big performance hit once you are doing more complex computations.

Comment: @mipa Thanks for the heads up. I edited from `Double` to `double`. :-)

Comment: Why multiply by 180/PI?

Comment: @DavidFinder: It just converts radians to degrees (if necessary): `degrees = radians * 180 / PI`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you create a **complete** example.

A Path (ellipse path by [Uluk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171856/javafx-2-circle-path-for-animation)) on which a Node (triangle) is moved. During each movement the rotation of the node is calculated and adjusted.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    double prevX = 0;
    double prevY = 0;

    double radiusX = 200;
    double radiusY = 100;

    double centerX = 600;
    double centerY = 200;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        try {

            // race track
            Path path = new Path();

            MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo(centerX - radiusX, centerY - radiusY);

            ArcTo arcTo = new ArcTo();
            arcTo.setX(centerX - radiusX + 1); // to simulate a full 360 degree celsius circle.
            arcTo.setY(centerY - radiusY);
            arcTo.setSweepFlag(false);
            arcTo.setLargeArcFlag(true);
            arcTo.setRadiusX(radiusX);
            arcTo.setRadiusY(radiusY);

            path.getElements().add(moveTo);
            path.getElements().add(arcTo);
            path.getElements().add(new ClosePath());

            path.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            path.setStroke(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
            path.setStrokeWidth(40);


            Pane root = new Pane();

            // car: arrow pointing right
            Polygon arrow = new Polygon(0, 0, 20, 10, 0, 20);

            root.getChildren().addAll( path, arrow);

            // lawn
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 400, Color.GREEN);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

            // movement: car path on race track
            PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
            pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(4000));
            pathTransition.setPath(path);
            pathTransition.setNode(arrow);
            pathTransition.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            pathTransition.setAutoReverse(true);

            // rotate car during movement
            pathTransition.currentTimeProperty().addListener(e -> {

                double rad = angle(new Point2D(prevX, prevY), new Point2D(arrow.getTranslateX(), arrow.getTranslateY()));
                double deg = Math.toDegrees(rad);

                arrow.setRotate(deg);

                prevX = arrow.getTranslateX();
                prevY = arrow.getTranslateY();

            });

            pathTransition.play();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate angle between source and target point in radians.
     * @param source
     * @param target
     * @return
     */
    public static double angle(Point2D source, Point2D target) {

        double dx = target.getX() - source.getX();
        double dy = target.getY() - source.getY();

        double angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

        return angle;

    }

}
```

[image]