# javafx position elements around a central point

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Apologies, as this is a rubbishy asked question, but I am totally flumped here about the best approach. I believe there must be something inbuilt or common practice for this but I can't find it and Google has turned up nothing of much value.

I have a javafx scene with a number of `Circle`s.

(Named below to illustrate the effect I'm trying to achieve)

```
Circle earth= new Circle(30, Color.web("blue", 0.5));

Circle moon = new Circle(30, Color.web("blue", 0.5));
Circle moon = new Circle(30, Color.web("blue", 0.5));
Circle moon = new Circle(30, Color.web("blue", 0.5));
```

all positioned:

```
setCenterX(300); 
setCenterY(300);
```

on a 600 by 600 scene.

I need the `moon` objects to be placed around the `earth` object. I don't care where, as long as they are `x` distance from the moon and not touching.

I initially looped through each object, checked for collision and using a recursive function moved the circle +10 on the`y` coord.

This worked but seemed like I was doing to much to effectively plot some objects on a circular path. (looping through each object then once all object where moved looping again to check the moving of the object hadn't had a knock on effect)

I have seen loads of tutorials as [SO questions such as this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171856/javafx-2-circle-path-for-animation) however they all show you how to plot a rectangle on a circular path. the Circle object doesn't seem to have the same methods.

Any help on how I go about this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just position them at equal angles around the center.

```
Pane pane = new Pane();

double centerX = 300 ;
double centerY = 300 ;
double radius = 30 ;

Circle earth = new Circle(centerX, centerY, radius, Color.web("blue", 0.5));
pane.getChildren().add(earth);

int numMoons = 3 ;
double distance = 100 ;

for (int i = 0 ; i < numMoons; i++) {
    double angle = 2 * i * Math.PI / numMoons ;
    double xOffset = distance * Math.cos(angle);
    double yOffset = distance * Math.sin(angle);
    double x = centerX + xOffset ;
    double y = centerY + yOffset ;
    Circle moon = new Circle(x, y, radius, Color.web("blue", 0.5));
    pane.getChildren().add(moon);
}
```

Or, put them all at `(centerX + distance, centerY)` and then apply different rotations:

```
Pane pane = new Pane();

double centerX = 300 ;
double centerY = 300 ;
double radius = 30 ;

Circle earth = new Circle(centerX, centerY, radius, Color.web("blue", 0.5));
pane.getChildren().add(earth);

int numMoons = 3 ;
double distance = 100 ;

for (int i = 0 ; i < numMoons; i++) {
    double angle = 360.0 * i / numMoons ;

    Circle moon = new Circle(centerX + distance, centerY, radius, Color.web("blue", 0.5));
    Rotate rotate = new Rotate(angle, centerX, centerY);
    moon.getTransforms().add(rotate);
    pane.getChildren().add(moon);
}
```

Or, if you want to define a fixed gap between them, it's not hard to show that the angle to increment by (in radians) is

```
incrementAngle = 2 * Math.asin((2 * moonRadius + gap) / (2 * distance) );
```

So you can do things like

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CirclesAroundCircle extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        double centerX = 300 ;
        double centerY = 300 ;
        double earthRadius = 30 ;
        double moonRadius = 30 ;

        Circle earth = new Circle(centerX, centerY, earthRadius, Color.web("blue", 0.5));
        pane.getChildren().add(earth);

        int numMoons = 3 ;
        double gap = 10 ;
        double distance = 100 ;
        double angleIncrement = 2 * Math.asin((2 * moonRadius + gap) / (2  * distance) );

        for (int i = 0 ; i < numMoons; i++) {

            double angle = Math.toDegrees(angleIncrement * i) ;

            Circle moon = new Circle(centerX + distance, centerY, moonRadius, Color.web("blue", 0.5));
            Rotate rotate = new Rotate(angle, centerX, centerY);
            moon.getTransforms().add(rotate);
            pane.getChildren().add(moon);
        }

        Circle orbit = new Circle(centerX, centerY, distance, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        orbit.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        pane.getChildren().add(orbit);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing, know I was making too much work for myself. Thanks