# JavaFX RotateTransition indefinite halts

Tags: animation, javafx

The problem with the code below is that between two animations there is a pause of about half a second. I'd like the node to spin continuously.

```
RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(2), syncNode);
rt.setFromAngle(0);
rt.setToAngle(360);
rt.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
rt.play();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Interpolator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Interpolator.html) used by default makes the rotation "speed up" at the start and "slow down" at the end, which is why you get the behaviour you described.

Use the `LINEAR` interpolator instead to get a animation with constant speed:

```
rt.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
```